# How to make a variable stored on the server

Tags: javascript, variables, server

How do you make a variable that is stored on the server of your script? So the value stays on it even when you go out. And it has to be worldwide. So if somebody increases the variable by one, somebody else on the other side of the world could see that change. This might have already been asked before, but I didn't see anything. Or else I didn't word the question differently. Anyway, could you give me a solution, or direct me to another variation of the question? Thanks!

Comment: Javascript runs on client side not on server side. So variable will be on client side only

Comment: Javascript is client side scripting language. So what ever you do on client side you need to send that those updates to the server. And Storing data on server side requires server side programming. So answer to your question is Using javascript alone its not possible to store server side variables. But yes you can use a server side technology such as PHP or ASP.NET etc. Which can help you to achieve what you need.

Comment: Move that to Database :/

Comment: Akshey Bhat, Manish - How is caveman life?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally when you increment a variable in your browser, the scope and life of that variable unfortunately is just the browser. To make it persist, you need to store it in a database on the server so that it persists across requests to your page. So your answer is, a database. They come in all flavours and sizes and complexities but you might be better off starting with something like `MySql`.

Answer (score 1):

Why didnt use database? If you love JavaScript so much, and won't to learn other language, you can use nodejs.

check this to get start using nodejs:

[https://google/MkVg6Q](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&client=firefox-b&biw=1304&bih=697&q=crud%20node%20js%20tutorial&oq=crud%20node%20js%20tutor&gs_l=serp.3.0.0i22i30l3.4141.5258.0.6774.6.6.0.0.0.0.140.733.0j6.6.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.6.731...0.raF2_aasDxE)